# Generating chains from an order of lists

Tags: algorithm, combinations

I am searching for how to accomplish something I've somewhat a grasp on, but do not:

I have n number of lists of varying size:

```
{A, B, C, D}
    {1,2}
       {X, Y, Z}
            ...to the nth potentially
```

How do I generate all possible chains of 1 item from each level A1X, A1Y, A1Z, etc. Its an algotrithmic and mathematic task, no its not homework(I know school is starting), its part of something I'm working on, I have no code --- I just need to be pointed in the right direction to formulate my terms.

Comment: 1) nested loops 2) loop of loops 3) recursion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(You didn't ask for code, but I tend to use Python for executable pseudo-code. You still need to translate the core algorithm to the language of your choice).

In effect, you are talking about forming the [Cartesian Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of the lists. It can be done in various ways. If the number of lists isn't known ahead of time, a recursive approach is the most natural.

Let `L1*L2* ... *Ln` denote the list of all strings which are of the form
`s1+s2+...+sn` where `si` in `Li` and `+` is the concatenation operator. For a basis you could either take `n ==1`, a single List, or `n == 0`, no lists at all. In many ways the latter is more elegant, in which case it is natural to define the product of an empty list of strings to be the list whose sole element is the empty string.

Then:

Return `['']` if `n == 0`

Otherwise return

```
[a+b | a ranges over L1 and b ranges over (L2 * L3 * ... * Ln)]
```

where `(L2 * L3 * ... *Ln)` was alread computed recursively (which will just be the empty string if n is 1).

The last list can easily be built up in a nested loop, or expressed more directly in any language which supports `list comprehensions`.

Here is a Python implementation which returns the list of all products given a list of lists of strings (abbreviated as `lls` in the code):

```
def product(lls):
    if len(lls) == 0:
        return ['']
    else:
        return [a+b for a in lls[0] for b in product(lls[1:])]
```

Tested like thus:

```
lists_of_strings = [['A','B','C','D'],['1','2','3'],['X','Y','Z']]
print(product(lists_of_strings))
```

With output:

```
['A1X', 'A1Y', 'A1Z', 'A2X', 'A2Y', 'A2Z', 'A3X', 'A3Y', 'A3Z', 'B1X', 'B1Y', 'B1Z', 'B2X', 'B2Y', 'B2Z', 'B3X', 'B3Y', 'B3Z', 'C1X', 'C1Y', 'C1Z', 'C2X', 'C2Y', 'C2Z', 'C3X', 'C3Y', 'C3Z', 'D1X', 'D1Y', 'D1Z', 'D2X', 'D2Y', 'D2Z', 'D3X', 'D3Y', 'D3Z']
```

In Python itself there isn't much motivation to do this since the `itertools` module has a nice product and the same product can be expressed as:

```
[''.join(p) for p in itertools.product(*lists_of_strings)]
```